# retrieve database from maxmind javascript

Tags: javascript, php, maxmind

I am trying to **retrieve country code via maxmind** javascript **but return null why** ?
** want to get timezone by country code.**

Once i got country code i want to implament it. i got timezone deta here. but javascript return null

https://github.com/maxromanovsky/php-maxmind-geoip/blob/master/timezone/timezone.php

```
 <script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#country").html( 'Country: ' + geoip_country_code() );
    <?php $country = geoip_country_code(); ?>
    </script>
<div id="country"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a local copy of http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js as 500 Internals server error is return to me. Also you are not using this properly, first you need to have `geoip_country_code();` when page is loaded, if this is actually JS function, and I don't get the PHP  part as there is no such function in PHP MaxMind code `geoip_country_code()`. In your php do following

```
<?php
include('geoip.inc');
include('geoipregionvars.php');
include('timezone/timezone.php');

$gi = geoip_open(PATH_TO_GeoIP.dat,GEOIP_STANDARD);

list($country_code,$region) = geoip_region_by_addr($gi, $IP_ADDRESS);
$timeZone = get_time_zone($country_code,$region);
```

Comment: I found in the terms and condition for ussage 
if you have free user, you can limited ussage of maxmind, Per ip 1 query. so you return 500 error. I  also return 500 error.

i want test a website but maxmind gives me only 1 result per ip ....

Comment: Just follow instructions from https://github.com/maxromanovsky/php-maxmind-geoip , download free maxmind db and you dont need their JS , you could develop you own in PHP , and no limits are imposed.

Comment: yes i got

<?php 
require("timezone.php");
print get_time_zone("IN","");
?>

when i use this i got right result but

how to get

"IN","" by ip ??

Comment: i uses : timezone/test_timezone.php

Comment: i got error

Notice: Use of undefined constant PATH_TO_GeoIP - assumed 'PATH_TO_GeoIP' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mas\timezone\test_timezone.php on line 9

Notice: Use of undefined constant dat - assumed 'dat' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mas\timezone\test_timezone.php on line 9

Warning: fopen(PATH_TO_GeoIPdat): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mas\timezone\geoip.inc on line 386
Can not open PATH_TO_GeoIPdat